# MQTT Authentication with same JWT Token

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth, jwt, mqtt

I'm trying to setup an architecture for my software-project.
As you can see in the drawing, as the client successfully logs in, he will receive a JWT (Node.js API). My Question now is, if it is a good practice to send this token to the MQTT Broker so the client can access the MQTT Broker directly and get live data. Is this how its done?
If not, how can i authenticate the client to the API and the MQTT Broker with just a single log-in?
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Let me know if u had implimented it succesfully and what changes in the broker u had to impliment to set up for this to work? I have Mosquitto as the broker and find it difficult to understand how to impliment JWT in the broker

Comment: The project was abandoned long ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that looks like a feasible approach. Given that the MQTT can validate the JWT, this setup reduces the need for the MQTT broker to communication with a different service to authenticate and authorize a request made by the client. The JWT is self contained, all that is necessary to validat it is the public key of the issuer or the shared secret used to sign the JWT.

Comment: So basically what i need to do is store the secret key on both platforms (api and mqtt broker) in order to verify the token i'm sending?

Comment: Yes, if you use a shared secret. Then the API server will use this secret to sign the JWT while the MQTT broker will use the secret to verify to JWT.